# How to provide file extensions for Bun to watch?

Tags: bun

I'm using `bun --watch src/main.ts` to run an express app with twig templates. When I change ts files, it reloads as it should. When I change twig files - it doesn't. `nodemon` has an option `-e js,twig`, where I can specify the extensions to watch. Is there a similar thing for Bun?

Comment: I think it's not yet supported. See this [issue](https://github.com/oven-sh/bun/issues/6216) for more detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nodemon -e ts,twig --exec 'bun src/main.ts'`

worked for me